# Android, sharedPreferences automatically remove the list of the unused preferences when upgrading an application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My app have had many releases and some of the earlier version sharedPreferences are useless.
What would be the best way to have the app itself sorting out the one that are still used and remove the unused one ?
Basically it would be like parsing the preferences XML's to extract the current android::key and by getting all preferences present on the device remove the one not being anymore in an XML.

Not sure I am very clear, but I have lot's of shared preferences not used anymore and having to establish the list manually can be source of problem.

Any hint would be great, 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Usually, there is no need to do this, as old preferences do not reduce performance in any way.

Comment: You can install an upgrade receiver ```android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED```, which will be called when your app is updated. There you can remove all keys you don't need. In the next version you can remove the receiver or adapt it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can go through the keys one by one removing any that you dont use anymore like this

```
Map<String,?> prefs = pref.getAll();
for(Map.Entry<String,?> prefToReset : prefs.entrySet()){
    if(prefToReset.getKey().equals("someKey")){
         pref.edit().remove(prefToReset.getKey()).commit();
    }

}
```

though there really is no performance benefit from doing this really

Comment: Thanks,

I agree no performance benefit, it just makes it cleaner and also avoid to "reuse" an old key (used x versions ago) that might have had a default  value that does not fit anymore ..

I know how to remove the keys, the main issue to automate this (I mean which one to remove) when they application is updated.
Ideally I would examine the xml of the preference screens and check if a key is present.
Thanks

Comment: There is no automated way, any automation you would have to build yourself